# How to pass condition statements to a mySql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am updating this question to better clarify what am looking for. I am passing an array to a function which is supposed to update a cart. I have two variables, `$isbn` and `$formatQuantity`.

Here is my problem before updating the database I need to check a few condition

1. check if `$isbn` exists, if it does just update `$formatQuantity`, if it does not create a column with `$isbn` as primary key
2. `$formatQuantity` could be softcover, hardcover, or ebook... I need to update the quantity of the right column so if format is softcover I need to add 1 to the current value of column softcover purchase..

Here is my code (P.s I know how to do everything else but I don't know how to check the condition with MySQL):

```
<?php
  function insertBook($db,$selection){
    $isbn;
    $format;


   foreach ($selection as $key => $value) {
       $isbn=$key;
       $format=$value;
       $change= explode(":", $format) ;
       $format=$change['0'];


   }


$query = "INSERT INTO cart (isbn, hardcover_purchased, softcover_purchased, ebook_purchased)
          VALUES (':isbn', ':format', 0, 0)";

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$success = $statement->execute();
$statement->bindValue(':isbn', $isbn);
$statement->bindValue(':format', $format);
$statement->closeCursor();

if ($success) {
  echo "section inserted using query insertNewSection_checkSuccess";
}
else{
  echo "Unable to insert new section using query insertNewSection_checkSuccess";
}
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Prepare a statement once, execute with the arguments from your Array. With PDO this is super easy. It's not clear which interface you're using here.

Comment: That array requires a bit of work to iterate over correctly, but `execute()` does take arrays it can bind for you, so that saves a lot of work if your data's in the right shape.

Comment: @tadman I have updated the question, I have completely rewritten it. I really need help with how to insert conditions into the MySQL querry..

Answer (score 1):

If i get your question, you could use split()  function it will  divide  a  string  into  various element based on the occurrence of pattern in string.
and returns an array of strings after splitting up a string.

Comment: I have updated the question..please look it over and see if you can help me.